# Retrieving User/Session info in Spring-Boot from another(parent) app

Tags: spring-boot

We have a spring boot application which is invoked by parent application when user clicks a link on it.

Parent application authenticates the user during login. Now, how do I retrieve the user/session info on my spring-boot app? I need to pass this user info to UI code (React) which is inside the resources folder.

**Parent Application** - This is a legacy app and **not** a spring-boot app. I am not not sure of it's actual implementation, also it is running in a separate VM. When clicking a menu on it, it pops up a model window where the spring-boot app is displayed to the user.

Comment: What do you mean by parent application? Do you have to separate Spring Boot applications running?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated the post with additional details. Parent app is not a spring-boot implementation.